# Installing matlab 2013a finding license file location

Tags: macos, matlab, installation

I downloaded Matlab R2013a on mac OSX 10.9 from the university isd page. And after installation key page, it asks me enter the full path of license file . I tried looking archieve, bin, license.txt. But no no there is nowhere like license.lic ??

Comment: Contact your university's IT desk?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about not available license files.

Comment: thank you so much I contacted already but no answer :/

Comment: Just make sure not to search for a `.txt` file, otherwise you will never find the `.lic`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default location for your license file (windows, 2012b 64bit) is

```
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\etc
```

If you don't find the license anywhere, only support can help you.

If you do find it, try putting a copy in this directory.

Comment: @ChaineSanBuenaventura I suppose you are not using 2012b. If you cannot find the license file, just contact mathworks support. Then please add the information here on how you succesfully resolved the problem so others may find it.